# Help finding files with the same filename (except what's inside parenthesis) and deleting the smaller size ones

Tags: command-line, files, gui, find, sort

I need to know how to find one or more files with the same filename (except what's inside parenthesis) and delete the one(s) with the smaller size, in a folder. I don't care if it's a GUI app or terminal command.

Example: Addams Family, The (USA) / Addams Family, The (World) / Addams Family, The (Europe) (En,Fr,De)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider something like this

Create an array-of-arrays, in which the first index is the common filename prefix obtained by removing any number of trailing *space-parenthetic-group* sequences, the second index is the full filename, and its value is the file size. Then for each prefix, sort the full filenames in descending order of size, and output the second onward. This will give you a list of files that are *not* the largest for each common prefix.

One way to implement this would be in GNU awk, for example

```
$ stat --printf '%s\034%n\0' -- *\(*\)* | gawk '
  BEGIN {
    RS="\0"
    FS=SUBSEP
  } 
  {
    pfx = gensub(/( [(][^)]*[)])+$/,"", "1", $2)
    a[pfx][$2] = $1+0
  }
  END {
    for (p in a){
      n = asorti(a[p], b, "@val_num_desc")
      for(i=2; i<=n; i++) printf "%s\0", b[i]
    }
  }' | xargs -r0 -n1 -- echo
```

(note that this will fail if any of the filenames contains the ASCII FS character, with octal value 034).

*If this outputs the correct files, then you can replace `echo` (or, for greater efficiency, `-n1` and `echo`) by `rm`.*

If there is only a single file of a given prefix, then nothing will be output for that prefix (so no file will be deleted). If there is more than one file of a given prefix with the same maximum size, all but one will be output for deletion - if you want to retain a specific file in this case (for example, the lexicographically first filename) then additional sorting would be required.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh, you could use an indicator function that returns TRUE if a file of the same prefix exists that is larger, and then use that function as a *glob qualifier*.

The case of multiple files of the same prefix having the same maximum size needs special consideration. If you use "size strictly greater than" as the only condition, then the indicator will return FALSE for each, and all will be retained. OTOH if you use "size greater than or equal", then it will return TRUE for each, and none will be retained. If you want any other outcome, then you will need a tiebreaker - the following uses the filenames' lexicographical weight i.e. it retains whichever file sorts first in the current locale. You may wish to modify the tiebreaker to use some other criterion such as the files' modification times.

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

myind () {

  local -A s
  local fname1=$REPLY
  local fname fsize fsize1

  local pat=${fname1/% \(*\)/ \\(*\\)}

  zstat -L -H s -- $fname1
  fsize1=$s[size]

  for fname (${~pat}) {

    [[ $fname -ef $fname1 ]] && continue

    zstat -L -H s -- $fname
    fsize=$s[size]

    # select for deletion if a larger file of the same prefix exists
    if (( fsize > fsize1 )); then
      return 0
    # tiebreaker - retain lexicographically first file
    # (might consider changing to most recent)
    elif (( fsize == fsize1 )) && [[ $fname < $fname1 ]]; then
      return 0
    fi
  }
  return 1
}

print -r -C1 -- *\(*\)*(.N+myind)
```

Save the above script to a file, make it executable with `chmod +x path/to/name-of-script`, then run it as `path/to/name-of-script`. For example if it is saved in your current working directory:

```
chmod +x ./name-of-script
./name-of-script
```

As written, the script merely prints out the names of the files that would be deleted. If it does what you want, then you can change the `print` command to an `rm` command.

Comment: I installed zsh, but...
zmodload: command not found
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
zstat: Hostmanager not responding initializing
bash: ((: [size]: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[size]")
bash: ((: [size]: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[size]")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
Warning: unknown mime-type for "-r" -- using "application/octet-stream"

Comment: Warning: unknown mime-type for "-C1" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "*(*)*(.N+myind)" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "-r"
Error: no such file "-C1"
Error: no such file "*(*)*(.N+myind)"

Comment: @NunoFonseca you seem to be trying to execute the script in bash regardless - I have added some usage instructions

Comment: Finally, some real help! Thank you! I want do this recursively, however. I have 15 folders I want to include in this process.

Answer (score -2):

Read `man find xargs stat sort tail cut` and do something like **UNTESTED**:

```
find . -type f -name 'Addams Family, The*' -print0 | \
xargs -0 -r stat --format="%s %N" | \
sort -rn | \ 
tail --lines=+2 | \
cut "-d " -f2- | \
xargs echo rm
```

Remove the `echo` from the last line when you're satisfied with the file list.

Comment: 1. output: : command not found
2. Addams Family was an EXAMPLE. I need to find ANY files with duplicate filenames.

Comment: 1. If you don't have a `man` command,  I have to ask if you're really running Ubuntu. 2. replace the regexp with `'\**(*'`, and store the results in a file, rather than piping it to `xargs rm`.